# What's the correct term for the lambda vs proc or Struct vs Class distinction?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I've started thinking of Structs as "struct-flavored classes" and lambdas as "lambda-flavored procs". Is there a more correct term for these distinctions?

To illustrate what I mean:

```
p = proc { |text| puts text }
p.inspect
                              #=> #<Proc:0x007fd9c135fd98@(irb):5>
# vs

l = lambda { puts 'foo' }
l.inspect                     #=> "#<Proc:0x007fbf33ad2830@(irb):7 (lambda)>"
```

...and similarly:

```
Point = Class.new
Point.class                #=> Class
p = Point.new
p.class                    #=> Point
p.inspect                  #=> #<Point:0x007fd9c1038ef8>

# vs

Point = Struct.new(:x, :y)
Point.class                #=> Class
p = Point.new
p.class                    #=> Point
p.inspect                  #=> "#<struct Point x=nil, y=nil>"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to differentiate classes vs structs or lambdas vs procs would be to consider them as related data structures with different levels of rigidity.

In Ruby, the class and struct are both data structures that are designed to bind data to code.  The struct does this in a very loose manner, with what amounts to an internal hash to store the data.  Generally they are considered to be more ephemeral than classes, as you would put less logic in them.  The class allows you to create a more concrete data structure that you intend to use in multiple places in your code base.  Creating a struct in Ruby does create a new class object (it calls to `rb_class_new` in C).

The difference in procs and lambdas in Ruby is thematically similar.  A lambda is a stricter proc (with argument checking and different return behavior).  It also does not expand array arguments or use `nil` in place of missing arguments.

This all amounts to how much structure you would like provided for you in the data structure of your choosing.  A hash can do what a class can if you only want key/value access to data.  One other important consideration in Ruby is how you want to organize your codebase.  You can usually do whatever you want to in Ruby, so you could make a hash that you used a prototypal based method declaration on that was cloned repeatedly through your code.  This would likely make your coworkers want to harm you though.  In general, classes are the data structure of choice or any significant data and logic binding.  Lambdas would be chosen when arguments are important or if you want to ensure you only return from the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official term for "lamdaness".

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F) talks about lambdas having "*rigid argument handling*" and having no "*tricks*"! Besides argument handling, an important difference is handling of the `return` keyword. See [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2012/01/10/javascript-needs-blocks/) for example.

As for `Struct`, it's simply important to realize that `Struct.new` does not return an instance of `Struct` but a new `Class` that inherits from `Struct`.

Comment: I propose "lambdacity". :)